# Get location value of Resource Group in a variable Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, servicebus

I have a powershell script to deploy a service bus namespace

This is the command i use to deploy it .

```
New-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace -ResourceGroup $ResourceGroupName -NamespaceName $ServiceBusNamespace -Location $Location
```

The above command expects a location parameter to be entered. I want that location value as the Location where my resource group is located . How do i extract the Location value of my resource Group ?

I tried various methods and failed. it shows **@{location=west us}** , when i tried this

```
$location = Set-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroupName -Tag @{} | Select-Object Location

Write-Host $location
```

Need help . Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$loc = Get-AzureRMResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroupName | select-object -expandproperty location
```

Well, if you want to `GET` something use appropriate verb.
or like this:

```
$rg = Get-AzureRMResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroupName
$rg.location
```

Comment: Thanks alot brother ! Worked :-)

Comment: in the case this answer helped you feel free to upvote\accept as answer ;)

Comment: Yup ! I Did , it shows you can accept the answer in 7 minutes :-)

Answer (score 1):

The below code works with Az powershell module.

```
$loc= Get-AzResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName   #Gets the resource group details and stores in $loc variable

$location= $loc.location   #Gets the location name from resource group properties and stores in $location variable

Write-Host $location   #outputs the resource group location
```